# How can I call file not under version control in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, computing

In opposite to - versioned - files that are under Source-Code-Version-Control system (i.e. Git/SVN), is there a way to call files that left deliberately out in one word?

Is word "un-versioned" ("non-versioned"?) valid construct?

Comment: Of course it's a valid construct. I'm not sure what rule you have in mind that says it isn't. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I would stick with the standard terms for the tool. Git generally calls files with a repo's path but not in the repo "untracked". It calls files explicitly marked in .gitignore as "ignored". So your file is untracked, and may also be ignored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: If we're really talking Git or SVN, I'd definitely stick with "untracked", but for generic documents that are not a part of a repo, I do refer to these documents as "unversioned".

Comment: @HotLicks English language questions are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Laurel - But this is a question about computer jargon.

Comment: @HotLicks Such questions have been off-topic since [at least 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277615/6083675) on SO. However, because it is a question about computer jargon *in English*, it is on topic on this site (although it may need some edits).

Comment: @HotLicks, alternatives? SO is not an option.

Comment: @Laurel, ready to make necessary changes.

Comment: @HotLicks, ie: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270220/antonym-of-portable-in-the-context-of-a-computer-programme?rq=1 , question clearly states jargon, and none objected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (informal) adjective I'd use is non-VC'd, as in "non-**V**ersion **C**ontrolled". For example:

> I do use source control, but putting everything under cloudsync is great for 1. Syncing personal notes, files, non-VC'd assets across machines and 2. Making sure that my working directory is available as-is across my machines even if I'm between commits or haven't pushed in a while.
>   <sub>[Put tmp files in an external dir with Ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46005819/6083675)</sub>

> In my case, the private layer would survive, but all my non vc'd snippets would be removed
>   <sub>[Recommended strategy for version controlling private layers](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10390)</sub>

> Oops, I guess I didn't enable/install helm-projectile properly, I no longer see non-VC'd files in helm-projectile-grep output
>   <sub>[There should be an extra function/option to do git-grep/grep within project files](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile/issues/16)</sub>

Comment: hm, how wide-spread is this abbr. (in industry, outside, in internet) especially together with "non-VC"? I mean, if I write something like this in business email-conversation, will they understand?